# Triggering event only on a change of variable output

Tags: swift, swift3

I have created the following coin toss program which also triggers an audio file with each coin toss every second. I'd like to know how to change this so that the audio only triggers when the result changes from a heads to a tails or vice versa. Not every second as it is now. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var times: Timer!
var timer: Timer!
var coinFlip : Int = 0
var coinResult : String = ""
var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!
let soundArray = ["note1", "note7"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    times = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(fiftyFifty), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(result), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    result()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func fiftyFifty() -> Int {

    coinFlip = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))

    return coinFlip
}
func result() -> String {

    if coinFlip == 1 {
        coinResult = "Heads"
print("Heads")
        playSound(soundFileName: soundArray[0])
    }
    else {
        coinResult = "Tails"
print("Tails")
        playSound(soundFileName: soundArray[1])
    }
}

func playSound(soundFileName : String) {
    let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundFileName, withExtension: "wav")
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL!)
    }
    catch  {
        print(error)
    }
    audioPlayer.play()
}
}
```

I've now changed it to add a new variable output from result(), coinResult. Not sure if this helps but hopefully might.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, when the coin flips, you want to play a song, in this case you can simply change your coinFlip declaration to that:

```
var coinFlip : Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        result()
    }
}
```

`didSet` is a property observer that observes and respond to changes in property's value.

> didSet is called immediately after the new value is stored.

You can read more about property observers in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html).

---

EDIT: Your code will be like this:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var times: Timer!
var timer: Timer!

// Change this
var coinFlip : Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        result()
    }
}

var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!
let soundArray = ["note1", "note7"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    times = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(fiftyFifty), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(result), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    result()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func fiftyFifty() -> Int {

    coinFlip = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))

    return coinFlip
}
func result() {

    if coinFlip == 1 {
print("Heads")
        playSound(soundFileName: soundArray[0])
    }
    else {
print("Tails")
        playSound(soundFileName: soundArray[1])
    }
}

func playSound(soundFileName : String) {
    let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundFileName, withExtension: "wav")
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL!)
    }
    catch  {
        print(error)
    }
    audioPlayer.play()
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alexandre, appreciate this. Reading up about didset I can see you are right but I'm quite new to swift and learning so I'm not sure how to implement this into my code. Could you show me please?

Comment: So this is now doing something quite different. Its still doing a ping every second but it's now putting in multiple heads or tails between each ping. After each ping it's then quite often doing more of the same coin toss. So it'll do 1 tail then a ping, 1 second later display 3 heads then a different ping but then some times it'll do 2 more heads and the second ping.

Comment: Result() activates every second to show a new head or tail from the random generator. As far as I can tell result() still needs to trigger every second as one coin toss but the didset doesn't need to be every second. Is the best way to have coinFlip output another variable which then goes into the didset activating the sound only upon a change in that new variable?